# Unity3D Integration in NativeApp - Keyboard.mm compiles but UnityKeyboard_GetText undefined symbol

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture, unity-game-engine

I successfully converted a Unity3D project to act more like a NativeApp (Storyboard's) with a way to switch to Unity.

Now I am trying to integrate Unity3D into a NativeApp.  Carefully replicating the Unity3D XCode project within an existing NativeApp.  Everything went pretty smooth except for this very frustrating error that makes no sense:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "UnityKeyboard_GetText(std::string*)", referenced from:
      KeyboardOnScreen::getText() const in libiPhone-lib.a(iPhoneKeyboard.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

An examination of libiPhone-lib.a shows the following:

```
libiPhone-lib.a: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
libiPhone-lib.a (for architecture armv7):       current ar archive random library
libiPhone-lib.a (for architecture i386):        current ar archive random library
```

I have verified that Keyboard.mm is being compiled and it contains the so called undefined reference.

UPDATE:

Basically there was some critical project build settings missing.  Most importantly the C++ lib being linked against (std vs gnu) and the run script for Unity projects.  I will post a more specific answer in two days.

Comment: Did you come across a solution that you could write an answer about? We are having the same issue.

Comment: I forgot about this.  The solution had to do with changing which C++ library is being linked against.  I can find you the exact settings next time I have the code up.  Basically to get you going now though, export an IOS project from Unity then compare the C/C++ settings in that project with yours.  The compiler and C/C++ library linked against needs to be the same.

Comment: My coworker figured it out from the clues you had left before. Thank you!

Comment: Would you share the solution? I got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

you must disable C++ 11 support for your unity generated project.